# How to convert C string to Python exception

Tags: python-3.x, cpython

I'm trying to figure out how to convert a C string such as `"RuntimeError"` or `"IOError"` to the corresponding Python exception `PyExc_RuntimeError` and `PyExc_IOError`.

If I were writing in Python, I could do something like `__builtins__.__dict__[name]`, but I can't seem to find the functions required to access `__builtins__` or to lookup a name in that module.

Comment: Are you writing a binary extension?

Comment: I'm cleanup up someone else's SWIG code.  There's actually a much longer question, but I decided to simplify it to its essentials.  C doesn't let you put `PyExc_RuntimeError` and its ilk into a constant table.  I need to use some constant token to represent the errors, and then convert the tokens into the errors.  I'm trying to avoid a large switch statement; it would be faster but harder to maintain.

Comment: I found a function `PyObject *PyEval_GetBuiltins()`. As I understand a comment the returned object should be a dictionary. Then you can use `PyObject *
PyDict_GetItem(PyObject *op, PyObject *key)` to get the exception class, I suppose.

Comment: @md2perpe.  Maybe.  The fact that this is part of introspection and the final paragraph on https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html?highlight=py%20builtins#module-builtins has me concerned that this isn't exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: What in the last paragraph makes you concerned?

Comment: @md2perpe.  You are right.  I was misinterpreting "this module" in the second sentence to refer to the current module instead of the "builtin" module.  This is clearly nonsensical.

Comment: I actually thought that you had misinterpreted "this module". That phrase confused me too a bit.